# Preventing LibreOffice from using smart quotes (“ ”) instead of (dumb) straight quotes?

Tags: openoffice, libreoffice, openoffice-calc, libreoffice-writer

I use LibreOffice Calc to make lists of programs with different parameters to run on an hpc cluster. For each batch of commands I must do a find and replace on the smart quotes, as they cause errors in command line arguments. It would be nice to cut this step out of my work flow. Does anyone know how I might change the default punctuation used?

Edit: Apparently the title font transforms dumb quotes into smart quotes.

Smart quotes have a different symbol depending on if they are at the start or end (“ ”)

Dumb quotes use the same symbol for the start and the stop ( " )

Answer (score 26, accepted):

- Goto *Tools* -> *Autocorrect Options*
- Uncheck *Replace* in the *Double Quotes* section of the *Localized Options* tab.

[image]

Comment: _Holy..._ Here I was, like a chump, expecting these options to be in the Options pane, with the rest of the, y'know, options. Maybe so many people find Autocorrect so annoying that they felt the need to give it its own, 'more prominent' menu entry... which, ironically, makes it less intuitive to find for an on-autopilot user like me. +1

Comment: this default feature is so annoying ><

Comment: fancy quotes kill